# How to save a bookmarklet link when using safari?

Tags: ipad, safari, url, javascript

How can I save the link of a bookmarklet in iPad’s safari? For example any of the bookmarklets in the following website? When I touch and hold, an option to save the link is not offered.

http://joemaller.com/translation_bookmarklets.shtml

Eventually, I would like to bookmark that bookmarklet. What I currently do is to open the above link in Firefox, then I save the link, then I create a bookmark in safari. I am wondering how can I do this without using a second browser.

Answer (score 2):

With only iPad and safari: open the link provided. Now, click on one bookmarklet suitable for you, and open it.

On the new window, in the upper part, there is one square with an up arrow, click on that and from the popup menu opened, choose "Add bookmark" and save it to your choice (a good one is Favorites page).

When need to translate a page, click first on the big " + ", choose the "Google Translate" icon and open it. Then copy/paste the address from your page to Google translate page.

Keep in mind that on Google Translate page, you can choose another "From" or "To" page, by clicking on the respective buttons.

Comment: It seems that your solution does not answer the question. In fact assume that one click on the first link in the above link, by your solution the address `http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A//joemaller.com/translation_bookmarklets.shtml&langpair=fr|en` is bookmarked. But actually the link is `javascript:%20void(window.open('http://translate.google.com/translate?u='+escape(location.href)+'&langpair=fr%7Cen',%20'French_to_English',%20'resizable,scrollbars,status'))`.

Comment: It seems you did not proceed as indicated in my answer - in fact you just bookmarked your original link(while I mentioned a second step). Still this is OK, at this stage you can edit it and modify it by pasting your link ```javascript....```.

Answer (score 1):

I use my own bookmarklet to save other bookmarklets (ironically) on ipad right from safari. While this can be done by other ways (modify long touch menu) they require editing system files. So obviously js comes to help as links are in DOM. All we need is to extract href from  tag. Here's the code of my simple bookmarklet, just copy and paste as any bookmark url:

javascript:if(!window.shclk)%7Bwindow.onclick=function(e)%7Be.preventDefault();oHref=e.target.href?e.target.href:e.target.src;try%7BdHref=decodeURIComponent(oHref)%7Dcatch(err)%7BdHref=oHref+err%7D;var%20newUrl=prompt(dHref+'%5Cn%5Cn'+e.target.outerHTML,(dHref?dHref:e.target.href));if(newUrl)document.location=newUrl;%7D;window.shclk=1;%7Delse%7Bwindow.onclick=null;shclk=0%7D;document.body.innerHTML+=('%3Cp%20id=%22scst%22%20style=%22position:fixed;left:10px;top:200px;font:100pt%20Arial;%22%3E'+shclk+'%3C/p%3E');setTimeout(function()%7Bdocument.getElementById('scst').remove()%7D,1000);

This works well on my iPad 3rd with iOS 7.1.1 (yes, a bit legacy)